# using custom CCK fields in node + Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, printing, cck

I'm new at drupal.

I created custom content type with CCK. Added some Phone, Address, Fax fields... Now I'm editing the related node. but in the node it just says **print $content** How can I use the custom fields I've created? maybe something like **print $field_name** ? anything like that?

appreciate helps!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use `$node->field_name[0]['view']` for most fields except for complex/compound fields like Address fields.
Take a look at [Example: Theming a Specific CCK Content Type](http://drupal.org/node/266817).

More information can be found and linked from [CCK For Themers](http://drupal.org/node/62462) from the Drupal Book pages.